# What is an alternative to jetty-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven

Is there any workable alternative to [jetty-maven-plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin)? This particular plugin is not supported properly. I even failed to find its source code repository.

What I need is an embedded container for integration testing.

Comment: Have you looked at ServletTester? http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/ServletTester

Comment: @Jeremy thanks, I will try it. Looks simple and effective, but I will have to try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very similar [Tomcat Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin). Works exactly the same, except... it uses Tomcat. You might also try [Maven Cargo plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin) that uniforms deploy process to several different containers/servers.

Answer (score 2):

There's an [embedded-glassfish plugin](http://embedded-glassfish.java.net/) that can be used for this.

Answer (score 0):

I often use an embedded jetty server that is started in the @beforeClass part of an junit test. That embedded jetty along with openejb provides most things you need without having to deploy your application anywhere